# Using the same counter for a javascript function and a php query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am seeking to increment a variable (counter) each time a DIV is clicked. 
The variable of the counter is used to select a question_id in another table so I need to reference it both in JAVASCRIPT and PHP .

Here is my code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
           var i= 1;
           $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#input01, #input02, #input03, #input04, #input05").click(function(){
         var value01 = $(this).attr('value'); 
         var value02 = i;                   
         $.post('input_answers.php',{value:value01,id_question:value02});
         var value02 = i+1;
         });    
});          
    </script>
```

Below is the query to insert the data ('input_answer.php')

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `answers` VALUES ('".$_POST['id_question']."' , '".$_POST['value']."' ) ");
```

My problem is that I'd like to incremen a variable to display a new question each time one of the DIV is clicked.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you using '1' in the _VALUES_ clause of the _answers_ table? Please show your _create table_ syntaxes for both tables. Also, where and how do you imagine to run the query for displaying the question(s)? Show the _select_ statement (as you think it should look like) please.

Comment: I used the '1' just to 'lock 'another value. This is not relevant to my pb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to pass mutliple values to server is:

```
$.post('input_answers.php',{value:value01, id_question:value02});
```

Your case:

```
$.post(
    'input_answers.php',   // URL
    {value:value01},       // data passed to server
    {id_question:value02}  // third argument, which is NOT passed to server
);
```

**Update**: correct way to increase your counter is to wait until request is over and add 1 in a callback:

```
$.post(
    'input_answers.php',
    {value:value01, id_question:value02},
    function () {
        // as your i is a global variable you can increase it here
        i += 1
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you u_mulder I corrected the syntax and the data is passed. Any idea about the counter issue?

Comment: What is the counter issue?

Comment: I have updated my code. I would like value02 to increment after each click and be able to use this variable when selecting my question  such as in: SELECT label_question WHERE id_question=value02.

Comment: You are only setting value02 to i + 1 (i is always 1, plus 1 is always 2). Just change 'var value02 = i+1;' to 'value02 = ++i;' (or better still 'var value02 = i; ' to 'var value02 = i++;' and remove 'var value02 = i+1;'.

Comment: Ask another question, I don't understand how clicking and selecting are connected.